# simple keyboard handler to replace interrupt 9 - assembly-

Tags: assembly, keyboard, interrupt, dosbox

im trying to write simple keyboard handler to understand more how it works and change the way it functions.

what i need from the handler is simple : recognize the button i pressed and send it to output (Screen)

```
KEY_HANDLER PROC FAR
 ;;;;
 ;body
 ;;;;
IRET
KEY_HANDLER ENDP
```

i have some questions that i don't understand

**1.** can i use int command inside an interrupt handler ?

**2**. when a key is pressed it sends scan_code to al and assci_code to ah, how should i use this     information to create an echo ?

any suggestion or help with the solution would be great !!

Comment: This may give you an idea what you're up against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882342/override-default-int-9h Note that he calls the old handler in the end. There's a lot to do!

Comment: You also might learn from this: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH20/CH20-5.html

Comment: @FrankKotler from what i understand is that when i press a key on the keyboard the scancode goes to port 60h
in al,60h transfers the scan code to al

Comment: Right. Then we need to look up the ascii code (if appropriate) in a Look Up Table, depending on capslock, shift, control, alt state. There are some "special cases" to be checked for. Then put ascii code and scan code in the keyboard buffer in BDA and bump head pointer. (I think I've seen int 16h used to do this) Finally(?) acknowledge the interrupt to the Programmable Interrupt controller (out 20h to port 20h or 0Ah, I think). Then `iret`. Easier to "chain" the original handler if you can. Nobody remembers this but geezers, and we forget a lot!